# How to loop through data file to fill in structs?

Tags: c

Program specifications:

Read questions from a data file in the following format:

> Question
>
> Number of choices
>
> N-amount of choices
>
> Correct answer

Example:

> What is the capital of France?
>
> 3
>
> Madrid
>
> Sydney
>
> Paris
>
> Paris

Present the user a question at a time and keep track of their score, etc, etc.

What I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 60
#define MAX_LIST_SIZE 15
#define MAX_QUIZ_SIZE 10

typedef struct question {
    char *question;
    char **choices;
    int n_choices;
    char *correct_answer;
} QUESTION;

typedef struct quiz {
    struct question *questions;
    int n_questions;
} QUIZ;

char *dupString(const char *s) {
// copies a string

    char *dup = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    strcpy(dup, s);
    return dup;
}

void free_choices(QUESTION *q) {
// free memory

    for(int i = 0; i < q->n_choices; i++) {
        free(q->choices[i]);
    }

    free(q->choices);
}


int ask(QUESTION *q) {
    // Return 1 for correct guess, 0 for incorrect guess.

    int choice;

    // Print the question
    printf("\n%s\n", q->question);

    // Print the choices
    for (int i = 0; i <= q->n_choices-1; i++) {
        printf("%d : %s", i+1, q->choices[i]);
    }

    // Get user guess
    do {
        printf("Select an answer [1-%d]: ", q->n_choices);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
     
        /* Not sure how to structure here*/
        if (strcmp(q->choices[choice-1], q->correct_answer) == 0) {
            // if correct return 1
            return 1;
        }
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > q->n_choices);
    // Incorrect
    return 0;
    }


struct question parseQuestion(FILE *pData) {

    int qIndex, numChoices; 
    char question[MAX_LINE_SIZE], temp[MAX_LINE_SIZE], choices[MAX_LINE_SIZE], correctAns[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    QUESTION q = {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL};

    // Eat first line = QUESTION
    fgets(question, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
    q.question = question;

    // Eat second line = NUMBER OF CHOICES
    fgets(temp, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
    numChoices = atoi(temp);
    q.n_choices = numChoices;

    // Allocate memory
    q.choices = calloc(q.n_choices, sizeof(char*));

    // Eat nth lines = CHOICES
    for (qIndex=0; qIndex<=numChoices-1; qIndex++) {
        fgets(choices, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
        q.choices[qIndex] = dupString(choices);
    }

    // Eat nth + 1 line = CORRECT ANSWER
    fgets(correctAns, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
    q.correct_answer = correctAns;

    return q;   
    }

int main() {

    int num = 0;        // question being asked
    int strikes = 0;    // incorrect guesses

    FILE* pData;

    char *filename = "tickle.txt";
    char c;

    if ((pData = fopen(filename, "r"))) {

        printf("Welcome to the 2014 Quiz-festival!\n\n");
        printf("Are you ready to begin? [Y/y]\n");
        c = getchar();

        if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {
            QUESTION question = parseQuestion(pData);
            ask(&question);
            free_choices(&question);
        } else {
            printf("Come back again.\n");
            return 0;
        }

    } else {
        printf("File failed to open.");
    }

    fclose(pData);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you to @alk how picked up my error, that is resolved.

What I still can't get is how to loop through the data file and populate the quiz structure with question structures.

So this is where I'm struggling at the moment. From what I can tell I'm pretty close to finishing this little program as long as I can get this to work.

Comment: Note that `dupString()` should really check that `malloc()` succeeds.  `if (dup) strcpy(dup, s);` is sufficient in the function.  Then the calling code needs to be aware that it could fail.  Alternatively, you can define that `dupString()` does not return on memory allocation error: `if (!dup) …report out of memory and error exit…`.  For test programs, fail fast is often a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`parseQuestion()` duplicates the choices but misses to duplicate the question as well as the answer.

Instead it simply copies the two arrays' addresses to the locally defined variable `QUESTION q` which is copied on return.

The memory for the question and answer strings is free'd on returning from the function, accessing it afterwards invokes undefined behaviuor.

Comment: Ah it works, fixed it. Thank you so much. Also I'm having trouble with how to actually populate the quiz struct with questions.

This works for a single question, but there will be multiple questions in the data file.

Any pointers on how to do this?